# Block Diagram Reduction

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory

i am trying to simplify this systems block diagram. I calculated something but I am not sure about it, is my reduction true?
Thank you.

[image: Initial Block Diagram]

[image: After i tried to reduce it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: block diagram]
Doing away with the pesky s for the time being;

- $E=R-Y$
- $X=EF+K_1R-K_2Y$
  $$\begin{align}
  Y&=GX\\
  \\
  &=G(EF+K_1R-K_2Y)\\
  \\
  &=G\left(F\left(R-Y\right)+K_1R-K_2Y\right)\\
  &=GFR-GFY+GK_1R-GK_2Y
  \end{align}$$
  Grouping all the Y's together;
  $$Y\left(1+GF+GK_2\right)=GR(F+K_1)$$
  $$\frac{Y}{R}=\frac{G(F+K_1)}{1+G(F+K_2)}$$
  The notationally-correct expression is hence;
  $$\frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}=\frac{K_1G(s)+F(s)G(s)}{1+K_2G(s)+F(s)G(s)}$$
  The block-diagram reduction is done in 4 steps as follows:
  [image: steps]